# Timestamp data sorting

Tags: timestamp

I have the following datasets in .txt format. I need to read in multiple files in and then sort the rows in chronological order using the timestamp as the sorting peg. I then need to remove the bad data points (duplicate time stamps). I am new to Python so any code snippets on the simplest method to do this would be appreciated.

```
Sample  Date Time   Elapsed Time (hr)   Power (mW)  Current (A)
1   2/2/2017 21:54  0.0002  61.7638 17.5781
2   2/2/2016 21:59  0.0833  61.8029 17.4072
3   2/2/2016 22:04  0.166   61.8422 17.3584
4   2/2/2012 22:09  0.249   61.8531 17.3584
5   2/2/2016 22:14  0.3317  61.8662 17.334
6   2/2/2015 22:19  0.4144  61.8711 17.3096
7   2/2/2016 22:24  0.4972  61.8675 17.3584
8   2/2/2013 22:29  0.5804  61.8754 17.3584
9   2/2/2016 22:35  0.6782  61.8741 17.334
10  2/2/2016 22:41  0.7748  61.8744 17.3584
11  2/2/2014 22:46  0.8606  61.8685 17.4072
12  2/2/2016 22:52  0.9535  1.0546  0.0244
13  2/2/2016 22:57  1.0406  61.7084 17.2607
14  2/2/2016 23:02  1.13    61.8275 17.3584
15  2/2/2016 23:02  1.2193  61.859  17.3096
16  2/2/2016 23:02  1.3089  61.8622 17.2852
17  2/2/2016 23:02  1.3981  61.8649 17.2607
18  2/2/2016 23:02  1.4872  61.8727 17.334
19  2/2/2016 23:29  1.5764  61.8698 17.3828
20  2/2/2016 23:34  1.6657  61.8741 17.2607
21  2/2/2016 23:40  1.7556  61.8767 17.2607
22  2/2/2016 23:45  1.845   61.8718 17.2852`


The sorted data should look like this:

`Sample Date Time   Elapsed Time (hr)   Power (mW)  Current (A)
4   2/2/2012 22:09  0.249   61.8531 17.3584
8   2/2/2013 22:29  0.5804  61.8754 17.3584
11  2/2/2014 22:46  0.8606  61.8685 17.4072
6   2/2/2015 22:19  0.4144  61.8711 17.3096
2   2/2/2016 21:59  0.0833  61.8029 17.4072
3   2/2/2016 22:04  0.166   61.8422 17.3584
5   2/2/2016 22:14  0.3317  61.8662 17.334
7   2/2/2016 22:24  0.4972  61.8675 17.3584
9   2/2/2016 22:35  0.6782  61.8741 17.334
10  2/2/2016 22:41  0.7748  61.8744 17.3584
12  2/2/2016 22:52  0.9535  1.0546  0.0244
13  2/2/2016 22:57  1.0406  61.7084 17.2607
14  2/2/2016 23:02  1.13    61.8275 17.3584
19  2/2/2016 23:29  1.5764  61.8698 17.3828
20  2/2/2016 23:34  1.6657  61.8741 17.2607
21  2/2/2016 23:40  1.7556  61.8767 17.2607
22  2/2/2016 23:45  1.845   61.8718 17.2852
1   2/2/2017 21:54  0.0002  61.7638 17.5781
```

Comment: And what did you try already? This is a website to help you, not to write code instead of you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_table('a.txt', header=None, encoding='utf-8', delim_whitespace=True)
print data.iloc[1:, 1:5].sort_values([1, 2])
```

Anyway, you need to have a attemp first.

Comment: Use `iloc` to slice by integer. Also, like `loc`, `sort_values` takes column names rather than position.

Comment: Seems, `data.loc[1:, 1:5]` automatically changed by pandas to `data.loc["1", "1":"5"]` as it works. So we see pandas is now more clever to have some implicit things for programers.

Comment: Whether or not it works fully depends on if it matches the expected index and column. I don't see why it would work to select columns in this example, as their names do not reduce to numbers. Anyway, I don't see why slicing is even needed. Right now, you are leaving out the first row (position 0).

Comment: No, here did not use the the columns name of the initial file, as the column name also has `blank` in name which make the table has many `NaN` column. In fact, I do not know how to handle it, so I directly bypass the first row, and use the the implicit column name `1, 2, etc`. `1, 2, etc` is the column name, not `Sample date time etc`. Do you have any solution to handle the first line of original file?

Comment: I would not even bother to try and use the data as provided in the question, but for properly formatted data, leaving out `header=None` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code using a loop through my text files:

`for i in Index:
    os.chdir(os.path.join(r'''C:\Lifetests''',sns[i])) 
    if 'Date Time' in open(sns[i] + '.txt').read():
        #df = pd.read_table(os.path.join('C:\Lifetests',sns[8], sns[8] + '.txt'), sep='\t', header=0)
        df = pd.read_table(sns[i] + '.txt', sep='\t', header=0)
        df['Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'])
        Time_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Date Time'])
        Time_sorted = Time_sorted.drop_duplicates(subset='Date Time', keep='last')

        #with open('C:\Lifetests',sns[8], sns[8] + '_t.txt', 'w') as f:

        #        Time_sorted.to_string(f)

        Time_sorted.to_csv('test1.txt', sep='\t')
    else:
        print("{} does not exist ".format(sns[i] + '.txt'))`

This works for one single file but I am getting funny results when using the loop and writing to file....I'm so close but yet so far.